# Trying to understand how this string-to-integer function works

Tags: c

I have been trying to figure out how to convert an inputted string into an integer. I found code for this function online:

```
 int toString(char a[]) {
 int c, sign, offset, n;
   if (a[0] == '-') {  // Handle negative integers
    sign = -1;
   }
   if (sign == -1) {  // Set starting position to convert
    offset = 1;
   }
    else {
     offset = 0;
   }
 n = 0;
  for (c = offset; a[c] != '\0'; c++) {
   n = n * 10 + a[c] - '0';
  }
  if (sign == -1) {
   n = -n;
 }
return n;
}
```

link [here](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-convert-string-to-integer-without-using-atoi-function)
The code works, but I don't quite understand why. Specifically, I don't understand how this part works:

```
      n = 0;
      for (c = offset; a[c] != '\0'; c++) {
       n = n * 10 + a[c] - '0';
      }
```

if n = 0, how does multiplying it by 10 affect the outcome? also, how does the for loop end if the limiting factor is a[c] != '\0'? How would a[c] ever equal null?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: This is not a tutorial service. If you have difficulty with code written yourself, please post it and explain what is going wrong with it.

Comment: n is only 0 initially, after that once you add in the `a[c]-'0'` it will change, and then can be affected by the multiplication later on.

Comment: Hint: multiplying by 10 is relevant on subsequent iterations. Obviously, not the first.

Comment: `a[c]` will equal `nul` when you reach the end of the string. Please read a good C primer. `nul` is not `NULL`. The first is an integer value. The second is a pointer value.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no PO effort shown & we are not here to teach C

Comment: PS don't learn from this "banana" code. UBs, poorly written.

Comment: Compile your code with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...), then use the debugger (`gdb`) to run it step by step

Comment: When you subtract `'0'` (ascii 48 or 0x30) from the characters you convert the char from its ascii value (see table [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)) to its numeric value. e.g. `'1'` = ascii 49. So 49 - 48 = 1.

Answer (score 1):

> the code works [...]

No it doesn't, because `sign` is not initialized, but used when the string does not start with a `-`. Technically, the code has *undefined behavior*.

Please forget that site; it is of low quality and will not teach you proper C programming. E.g. these are the warnings produced by clang:

```
$ cc -c -Wall x.c
x.c:4:7: warning: variable 'sign' is used uninitialized whenever 'if' condition is false
      [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
  if (a[0] == '-') {  // Handle negative integers
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
x.c:8:7: note: uninitialized use occurs here
  if (sign == -1) {  // Set starting position to convert
      ^~~~
x.c:4:3: note: remove the 'if' if its condition is always true
  if (a[0] == '-') {  // Handle negative integers
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
x.c:2:14: note: initialize the variable 'sign' to silence this warning
  int c, sign, offset, n;
             ^
              = 0
1 warning generated.
```

Any site claiming to teach C must use examples free of warnings (unless the point of the code is to demonstrate errors).

And did you realize that the function name `toString` has it backwards? It should be `fromString` or `toInteger`. That's some lousy quality assurance on that site.

Comment: No  @Jens you have got the warning but this part is NOT the UB. He checks for the one particular value. sign has any other value (and it is the problem with uninitialized local variables) the code behaves in the absolutely defined way.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Then your understanding of what constitutes undefined behavior is not the same as the C Standard spells it out: *C99 # J.2 Undefined behavior*, The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.8, 6.8).

Answer (score 0):

n equal 0 on the first iteration, after one iteration n equal the value of a[c]. See Horner scheme to understand how it mathematically works.
The -'0' is here to convert the results into integer.

Answer (score 0):

'\0' is the termination character of the string and the multiplication * 10 is to calculate the correct value of tens, hundreds etc...